# How to create a tuple with a string and an int?

Tags: python, string, integer, tuples

input:

```
animal: 'cat'
number: 8
```

output:

```
('cat', 8)
```

I tried to do this:

```
tuple(animal, number)
```

but it gives me an error saying i have 2 arguments instead of 1.

I tried to do this then:

```
tuple[animal, number]
```

but I get this:

```
tuple['cat', 8]
```

can someone help me?

Comment: `t = (animal, number)` - using [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) requires you to pass it an iterable, so it'd be `t = tuple([animal, number])`.

Comment: thank you it worked!!!! I know it was a really dumb question and easy to get but I swear i tried and it would not work so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, if you want to use [`tuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) you need to provide an iterable e.g.,

```
>>> animal = 'cat'
>>> number = 8
>>> tuple([animal, number])
('cat', 8)
```

or

```
>>> tuple((animal, number))
('cat', 8)
```

However, it may be easier and more readable to use the following:

```
>>> (animal, number)
('cat', 8)
```

*Note that it is actually the comma which makes a tuple, not the parentheses:*

```
>>> animal, number
('cat', 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to push animal and cat into a single list first, then create a tuple based on your list. tuple() takes only one argument, as that error indicates

```
animal = 'cat'
num = 8
mylist = [animal, num]
tuple(mylist)
```